# Drush Make and the Windows maximum path length

Tags: 7, commerce, drush

When building Commerce Kickstart on Windows, using Drush Make, a customer has this problem:

```
copy(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\make_tmp_1449319094_5662dab66a8f0
\__build__\profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\contrib/commerce_discoun
t/modules/commerce_discount_usage/includes/views/handlers/commerce_disc
ount_usage_handler_field_commerce_discount_analytics.inc): failed to
open stream: Invalid argument filesystem.inc:267
```

It results in the Drush error "Project commerce_discount (7.x-1.0-alpha6) could not be downloaded".

The build works on non-Windows platforms.

I notice that the file path is 264 characters long, and I suspect this is a problem of the Windows `MAX_PATH` constant (variously quoted on the web as being 255, 256, or 260 characters).

Is there a way to get around this?

I should note: I have read the drupal.org issue about Kickstart on Windows (https://www.drupal.org/node/1648992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drush temporary directory can be set manually in the environment variable `TEMP`. So something like:

```
mkdir -p /c/drushtmp
TEMP=/c/drushtmp drush make [...]
```

can neatly solve the MAX_PATH problem for the temporary directory.

Answer (score 1):

What about temporarily changing the TMP and/or TEMP variable to C:\tmp (in stead of C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp)? It might be just enough ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I answered with that myself about 2 minutes before you :) see below

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is an MSDN article that has a solution:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

> To specify an extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very long path".

So, perhaps you can modify the install script to use this prefix before trying to install?

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped there might be some kind of way to do this at the OS level, because patching Drush is a little bit out of scope although probably worth trying...

Comment: It turns out PHP can't use that prefix, it prevents it deliberately according to Pierre Joye in this php-internals thread: http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?7,627200

Comment: Blerg! (facepalm)